# Why user is able to edit comments in multiple textareas in the same time?

Tags: bug, comments, design

By accident I have clicked *edit* link on comment twice.

After first click I have textarea for editing it (it is normal and expected behavior).

But on second and third click on *edit* I get garbage:

- second

  > [image: second click on edit]
- third

  > [image: third click on edit]

Seems to be an unexpected behavior or bug.
If I remember correctly, it did not exist in previous version of site layout.

I'm using Firefox ESR 52.9.0 if it matters.

Can somebody confirm this issue?

Comment: I get the exactly the same behaviour using `Vivaldi 1.15.1147.55 (Stable channel) (64-Bit)`.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on mother meta: [Repeatedly clicking the edit button causes chaos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313137)